# Invert values of colour in CSS

Tags: python, css

I have a CSS file where there are colours defined for certain elements. I want to invert the colours of these elements using some Python script. The format of colours are

- #XXX; or #XXX followed by space
- #XXXXXX; or #XXXXXX followed by space

I am able to grab the pattern using following regex expression:
 (\#)([a-fA-F0-9]*)(\;\w)

The problem is I am not able to figure out how to use it. I tried sed but it doesn't allow expression evaluation.

I may be wrong in assessment of my initial requirement.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you can get the hex values?

Comment: yes but don't know what to do with them, I am not that great at python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some pretty basic code that can invert hex.

```
# function takes in a hex color and outputs it inverted
def invert(color_to_convert): 
    table = string.maketrans('0123456789abcdef', 'fedcba9876543210')
    return '#' + color_to_convert[1:].lower().translate(table).upper()
```

Because to invert the chars just need to be turned around you can easily you need to switch zeros to f's and f's to zeros.